# Strange phonegap device ready event behaviour

Tags: cordova

I am trying to get the device ready event to work on the phonegap 3 helloworld default app.

html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
```

javascript

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    alert('welcome!');
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};
```

This code works ok and will fire my welcome alert when I open the app. However if I comment out either of the lines:

```
<p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
<p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
```

The welcome alert will no longer fire. What is going on here I have no idea what mechanism phonegap is using to create this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here isn't with phonegap, but rather the `receivedEvent` function causing an error. If you move the `alert` before the call to `receivedEvent`, you should see that the `deviceready` event is still fired properly.

The actual problem is that line

```
var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
```

gets the `<p class="event listening">..</p>` element from the DOM. Since you remove that element, the `listeningElement` will be `null`. Now the call

```
listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
```

will fail because of that.