# Unable to get property 'querySelector' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, windows-phone

I'm facing this error:
JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'querySelector' of undefined or null reference

Im trying to make a contact pick on Cordova. This works good on iOS and Android. On windows phone, the apps runs but then crashes with this error. Here is where it crashes (var listeningElement). I searched a lot but can't get a solution. Anyone could help me to fix it? thanks:

```
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
```

Comment: Show us you HTML markup. With your information, I guess you have conditions that makes your `parentElement` not appear on windows phone.

Comment: did you wrap the following codes on load? there is a possibility that the Javascript run first before the page loads.

Comment: which cordova plugin are you using? Are you sure it is supported on windows?

Comment: My HTML is just a button. But inside the html I have two functions

Comment: And yes, the plugin is supported on windowsphone. I used it before. but now im doing something wrong.... What should I run on load @SecretCoder ?

Comment: onload (){
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}

Run like this or refer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37254010/5870896

Comment: bad news..., it guives me the same error....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research the solution that resolved my issue was this: [Strange phonegap device ready event behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627589/strange-phonegap-device-ready-event-behaviour)

that is put this line back in your index.html

```
    <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
        <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
        <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
    </div>
```

good luck

Comment: Hi. Thanks. It solved the problem. But now I get other error. It open contact List, but when I pick, intead of get number and show me on my app, it stops on throw err on eval code [dynamic]. I dont know what file is that. I dont have it. and now?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following:

1. wrapping it in onload as others suggested
2. moving the js file to the header
3. moving it to the jquery ready function

Maybe one of these works for you, but all I have established so far is that it probably has to do with the order of things!